# What is the easiest way to save this markers/coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My program downloads the position with GPS and puts on the place marker. Now i thinking, what is the easiest way to save this markers/coordinates. 
I want to expand the program to include new features such as copy all my markers to server and from server to application again. I do not have experience, this is my first larger program. I also thought about a database.

What do you recommend me for the first time? I would like it to be easy.

Comment: Put them on an ArrayList and save it on SharedPrefferences

Comment: when user saves it on sharedprefference and will send this in server online, other phone with this same application will be able to download this ?

Answer (score 0):

`Markers` represent `latitude` and `longitude` of particular location on geographic surface.

You can save Marker's lattitude and longitude and its meta data like color, name etc, to local `Sqlite db (More flexible)` or `Shared Preferences (Easy to start with)` and display whenever you want.

Comment: when user saves it on sharedprefference and will send this in server online, other phone with this same application will be able to download this ?

Comment: Do you have any sort of login or UserIds per user?

Comment: i dont have login/users,
i read on the internet, sqlite db is only local/offline database, it is true ? whether it is possible to connect an application for android to an external database?

Comment: Sqlite db is local db. which can not be directly connected to your server db.
You would need to make http calls to get data from server db to local device db and same for sending local device db data to server db.

Comment: Look for some examples on how to make http calls in android, and how to use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check this [documentation](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in-sqlite-from-google-maps-android-api-v2/) that shows how to Store and Retrieve locations in SQLite from Google Maps Android API. This documentation will show you the steps that you need to connect your app with the database. It also show you some sample code that you can copy. This sample code can serve you as guide to make this tutorial easy.